# C Pointer and arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I was wondering what this statement in c means

```
   MDMA_Sobel_In_Des.StartAddress   = (void *) (&Sobel_In_Buf0[0]);
```

Specifically the right hand side statement. What is the role of (void*), why didn't the programmer just assign the address of the variable (&Sobel_In_Buf0[0]) directly to the StartAddress, why the (void *) keyword here. Is this even a variable in the first place? I am very new to c so excusise me if I sounded stupid.

Comment: You dont give the relevant declarations or types (what are `MDMA_Sobel_In_Des`, `StartAddress`, `Sobel_In_Buf0` ?). IMHO the `(void*)`  could be for readability reasons.

Comment: `(void*)` is casing the pointer to type void. without seeing the `StartAddress`definition, it would be hard to say what is the meaning

Comment: what do you mean casting the pointer to type void, is that mean the pointer can point to any data type. that is my point i need to know what type void in this case is, casue if i try to show you the code it will be  so long. i am using a library, Balckfin Processor.

Comment: `void*` is a generic pointer.  Any pointer can be converted to `void*`, and can then be converted back to its original type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression needs to be read from right to left, and from inside to outside:

1. `Sobel_In_Buf0[0]` takes the first element of the array `Sobel_In_Buf0`.
2. `(&Sobel_In_Buf0[0])` takes the *address* of the first element of the array `Sobel_In_Buf0`.
3. `(void *) (&Sobel_In_Buf0[0])` casts the address of the first element of the array `Sobel_In_Buf0` to `void*`.

That cast may or may not be necessary.  If `MDMA_Sobel_In_Des.StartAddress` is a `void*`, then it is not necessary.  It it's some other type of pointer, an `INT_PTR`, or something else, then the cast may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of `MDMA_Sobel_In_Des.StartAddress`. Assigning a `void*` to `MDMA_Sobel_In_Des.StartAddress` is OK but assigning `&Sobel_In_Buf0[0]` might not be.

If the type of `&Sobel_In_Buf0[0]` can be assigned to `MDMA_Sobel_In_Des.StartAddress`, then the use of `(void*)` is unnecessary. Otherwise, it is necessary.